# How to not be ignored when talking to another photographer with significantly better gear?

Tags: philosophy

I have a 60D and I was using the kit 18-200mm lens and I saw a bunch of photographers set up at spot to get a picture of Seattle. There were 3 different people with 600mm L lenses ($7000). I went up to one of them and just asked if they were there to take pictures of the moon an he said "no" and then just turned around and looked at the view.

Do you have tricks to peaking a professional photographers interest when you are carrying amature gear?

Comment: This is independent of the gear the photographer has, but it depends more on his personality and mood. This means that there are no suitable answers to your question.

Comment: If a photographer is ignoring you because of your gear, then they're not worth your time anyway.

Comment: if you feel your gear is what makes people ignore you, you will probably exert an attitude that makes you appear uninteresting to talk to for those others. I don't care about gear, but if someone comes up and flaunts his in order to appear an expert, I ignore him whatever the gear is.

Comment: If I'm photographing, or preparing to photograph, making small talk with a stranger is just about the last thing I want to do. I'd rather focus (ha!) on what I'm doing. If you want to meet and talk with photographers, you might be better off at a camera club, or an organized photowalk.

Answer (score 3):

IMO, you cannot do anything. It depends on the person. I've seen top notch photographers being very down to earth and explaining stuff to people with point and shoot cameras. I've also seen people with entry level cameras being haughty and arrogant as if they own the world.